# Newline literal doesn't make newline

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, literals

I have a custom element:

```
<GroupFields
 header={`text \n (highly recommended)`} // output: Single line
>
</GroupFields>
```

Inside this element I have:

```
<div>{header}</div>
```

But my \n doesnt make new line, why?

Comment: Try `<br>` instead of `\n`

Comment: <br> was recognized as text @AHMEDSAJJAD

Comment: _“why?”_ - because that’s how default whitespace handling in HTML works …? If you missed these basics, you should go read up on them. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Whitespace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `white-space: pre` css attribute

```
div {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

Comment: This  transformed text to single line